# Civic inspire s 2003 possible reason for lean fuel? P0171

Tags: honda, civic, cel

I have little practical knowledge but am willing to learn. The check engine light keeps coming on, sometimes it goes out on its own but then comes back on.I would like to try and fix the problem myself if possible, here are the freeze frames from 2 times it has come on;

[image][image]

Can anything definitely be ruled out from this data?

It is my understanding that if there were a leak in the vacuum system the stft would drop when being held at 2500 rpm for half a minute or so? After holding at 2500 its drops to 0 as soon as I release the throttle, I don't know if this is of any significance?

[image][image][image]

Comment: I will add I know a faulty o2 sensor can be a cause of this however the voltages from the o2 sensors seem to be fine. The upstream voltage oscillates between 0.8 and 0.2 and the downstream stays flat at 0.6

Comment: Sounds like a vacuum leak to me.

Comment: But from what I gather after the car has been held at 2500 rpm for half a minute or so the stft should drop if it was a vacuum leak but it only drops after the throttle has been released